# como eu faço pra uma tabela ir mostrando tabelas

Tags: funções, lua, recursão

queria fazer uma função que faz tipo alg como a coisa abaixo

```lua
for i in pairs(v) do
    if type(v[i])=="table" then
        for j in pairs(v[i]) do
             if type(v[i][j])=="table" then
                 print("...")
             else
                 print(i,j,v[i][j])
             end
        end
    else
        print(i,v[i])
    end
end
```

mas que funcionasse pra indefinidos numeros de tabelas dentro de outras, tipo
{{{{{1},{2},3},{4},5},{6},7},{8},9}

é possivel fazer uma função pra isso?

http://ideone.com/22Ddmf --exemplo citado acima xP

Comment: Respondida em  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580849/how-to-make-a-function-version-of-this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de uma função recursiva. Veja o exemplo abaixo na [demonstração on-line Lua](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo). Ligue `dump` a sua tabela em vez de `_G`.

```
-- globals.lua
-- show all global variables

local seen={}

function dump(t,i)
    seen[t]=true
    local s={}
    local n=0
    for k in pairs(t) do
        n=n+1 s[n]=k
    end
    table.sort(s)
    for k,v in ipairs(s) do
        print(i,v)
        v=t[v]
        if type(v)=="table" and not seen[v] then
            dump(v,i.."\t")
        end
    end
end

dump(_G,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ou mais fácil ainda, use o

```
json.cod(tabela)

--saída: { "matriz": [ "filhos" : [ "netos" : [ 1,2,3] ] ]}
```